# Java: Update value of nested array node in JSON file

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Because of the project requirement, I have to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` library to parse JSON data cannot use other JSON libraries available.

I am new to JSON parsing, so not sure if there are better options here?

I would like to know how can I update a string value in an `Array` node in the JSON file.

Following is a sample JSON. Please note this is not the entire file content, it's a simplified version.

```
{
  "call": "SimpleAnswer",
  "environment": "prod",
  "question": {
    "assertions": [
      {
        "assertionType": "regex",
        "expectedString": "(.*)world cup(.*)"
      }
    ],
    "questionVariations": [
      {
        "questionList": [
          "when is the next world cup"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is the code to read JSON into java object.

```
byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PATH_TO_JSON));
JsonNode jsonNodeFromFile = mapper.readValue(jsonData, JsonNode.class);
```

To update a root level node value e.g. `environment` in the **JSON file** , I found following approach on some SO threads.

```
ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode)jsonNodeFromFile;
objectNode.remove("environment");
objectNode.put("environment", "test");
jsonNodeFromFile = (JsonNode)objectNode;
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(PATH_TO_JSON);
file.write(jsonNodeFromFile.toString());
file.flush();
file.close();
```

QUESTION 1: Is this the only way to update a value in JSON file and is it the best way possible? I'm concerned on double casting and file I/O here.

QUESTION 2: I could not find a way to update the value for a nested Array node e.g. `questionList`. Update the question from `when is the next world cup` to `when is the next soccer world cup`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ObjectMapper` to parse that JSON, it is very easy to parse and update JSON using pojo class.

use [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert your json to java class, just paste your json here n download class structure.

You can access or update nested json field by using . (dot) operator

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString="{\"call\":\"SimpleAnswer\",\"environment\":\"prod\",\"question\":{\"assertions\":[{\"assertionType\":\"regex\",\"expectedString\":\"(.*)world cup(.*)\"}],\"questionVariations\":[{\"questionList\":[\"when is the next world cup\"]}]}}";
    TestClass sc=mapper.readValue(jsonString,TestClass.class);

    // to update environment
    sc.setEnvironment("new Environment");
    System.out.println(sc);

    //to update assertionType
    Question que=sc.getQuestion();
    List assertions=que.getAssertions();
    for (int i = 0; i < assertions.size(); i++) {
        Assertion ass= (Assertion) assertions.get(i);
        ass.setAssertionType("New Type");
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. No need to deal with JSON hierarchy anymore. I could easily parse the data to and from java object and the file, update properties and write it back to the file.                                                           
#1) Read data to java object: TestClass testClass = mapper.readValue(new File(FILE_FULL_PATH), TestClass.class);   #2) update java object as Pranay suggested #3 write object back to the file: mapper.writeValue(new File(FILE_FULL_PATH), testClass);